# Query function in Google Sheets - Get non-empty last cell in a column depending on another column

Tags: sql, function, google-sheets

I'd need to retrieve the last non-empty cell in a column based on changes on the adjacent column.

In the example below, the yellow cells are my target.
They are defined by a change in column A.

[click here to see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJxs5.png)

I already managed to do this with normal functions as seen in the picture:

```
=INDEX(ArrayFormula(FILTER(B2:B20,A2:A20=D2)),ArrayFormula(MATCH(0, FILTER(B2:B20,A2:A20=D2),-1)),1)
```

I need now to do it with query function as the results must automatically update as an importrange grows.

So far this works - but I still would need to create proper dependancy on column A:

```
=QUERY(A2:B20, "select A, B where B is not null limit 1 offset "&(COUNT(A2:B20)-1))
```

like so:
[click here to see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNnQV.png)

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

PS: Using solution provided by Player0 to my real data here:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQFrx.png)
I cannot get to "unsort" by the first column, setting `sort_column` to 0 does not work. Basically I need to keep the order of elements in column A the same at all times - and apparently SORTN cannot do it.

To apply it to the main example - if column A was made of a,c,d,b (instead of a,b,c,d) I would have to keep it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task can be accomplished in two steps:

1. determine the rows that contain the desired data
   `=index(query({A2:B20,ROW(A2:B20)},"select max(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label max(Col3)''"))`
   and assemble the result to a regular expression using formula `JOIN("|", -- query result --)`
   [image]
   the result we have a string: 5|11|14|19

2. use a new query to output the values from the previously found rows `=index(query({A2:B20,ROW(A2:B20)},"select Col1,Col2 where Col3 matches '"&  join("|",query({A2:B20,ROW(A2:B20)},"select max(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label max(Col3)''")) &"'"))`
   [image]

*the range `A2:B20` is used for the example, but the formula also works with the open range `A2:B`*

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=SORTN(QUERY(SORT(A2:B, ROW(A2:A), 0), 
 "where Col2 is not null"), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(SORTN(QUERY(SORT({A2:B, ROW(A2:A)}, ROW(A2:A), 0), 
 "where Col2 is not null"), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), 3, 1), 9^9, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I do not get to apply it successfully to my real data. I made an edit including a screenshot to my main text. Cannot "unsort" by first column.

Comment: @Lore456 np, answer updated

Comment: Hi @player0 Could you explain what the formula is doing, please? What does "9^9" do, for example?

Comment: @Dannid sure. 9^9 is just a big number. could be any number you wish (10000, 4546868461, 999999, etc.) it just needs to be higher than the total number of rows. if so then the meaning of 9^9 is literally "output all rows"

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't realize you were just putting in an arithmetic expression there.